# Java Define char Instance Variable

Tags: java, char, instance-variables

I am currently doing exam revision questions for Intro to Programming and I came across this question.

> Define a char instance variable academicLevel to store the academic level for the employee. The possible values for academic levels are in the range A—E (A=associate lecturer, B=lecturer, C=senior lecturer, D=associate professor, E=professor).

And I'm not exactly sure how it wants me to 'define'. Just like this?

```
private char academicLevel;
```

Comment: These instructions are unclear; and you shouldn't expect that we can magically clarify them for you. I guess more than an educated guess, such as the answer you got ... isn't possible here. From an "assignment" point of view, the interesting part would of course be "validation" of user inputs; and ways how to "improve" the data model (going from single-char to enum for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is asking you to define a char instance, just like you did, and then implement some code (ie : a switch) to filter the possible values